# RegExp валидность URL

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
var re = /^(https?:\/\/)?([0-9a-z\.-]+)[^-]\.([a-z]{2,9}\.?)([\/#].\S*)*$/i;


re.test("http://zcontest.ru/dir%201/dir_2/program.ext?var1=x&var2=my%20value");
re.test("http://zcontest.ru/dir%201/dir_2/program.ext&var1=x&var2=my%20value");
```

Ребята, что нужно дописать, что бы передача параметров не могла начинаться с &, как во втором примере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заменил части пути с `\S*` - любых непробельных символов на `[^\/\?]+` - не слеши/не вопросы.
Добавил требование наличия вопроса `\?` после всего этого.

```js
var re = /^(https?:\/\/)?([0-9a-z\.-]+)[^-]\.([a-z]{2,9}\.?)(\/[^\/\?]+)*\?/i;


console.log(re.test("http://zcontest.ru/dir%201/dir_2/program.ext?var1=x&var2=my%20value"));
console.log(re.test("http://zcontest.ru/dir%201/dir_2/program.ext&var1=x&var2=my%20value"));
```